# Gallery Shows Shadow in Android

Tags: android

i am develop project with gallery control in android.but,i have some problem in gallery control i am scroll one image to next image shows shadows like starting image not shadow in gallery control and i am scroll to next image to shows shadow for all images in gallery control.i want remove shadow in gallery control.

i am getting output below screen shot:

[image]  i

i am scroll to next image output below screen shot:

[image]

here's my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:id="@+id/lay_linear"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="430dp"
        android:layout_weight="2.50" />

</LinearLayout>
```

i want remove shadows on gallery control.can help me any one greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code for remove unselected shawdows:

```
galleryview.setUnselectedAlpha(1);
```

Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"`

Comment: have tried same problem! i am tried     <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="430dp"
        android:layout_weight="2.50"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />

Comment: Why not use @android:color/transparent instead #00000000?